# Reusing the same methods(functionality) in two different classes in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I was wondering how I can reuse some code in multiple files in xcode.
To elaborate, 
I have two classes, InviteViewController and FindFriendsViewController.
InviteViewController is of type XViewController and FindFriendsViewController is of type YViewController.
In both InviteViewController and FindFriendsViewController, I have a button that does the same thing, i.e, shows an action sheet with options like 'Send SMS', 'Send Email', etc.
As I am not an expert in iOS development, I wanted to know what some good techniques are to reuse code in such situations?
Is there a way I can write a common file which creates and performs action button click events in both these files? Should I create a NSObject file and import the NSObject file in both the classes, InviteViewController and FindFriendsViewController?
Is there a more sophisticated way of doing so? Is the method I described the correct implementation in this situation?

Any help and advise in doing so would be great!
Thank you in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so many capabilities to do this.

u can create a static class, u can create a singleton , u can create protocol.

simple example of one way:

`h.file`

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject

+(void)sendEmail;
+(void)sendSMS
```

`m.file`

```
@implementation ClassName
+(void)sendEmail {
   // some code
}
+(void)sendSMS {
    // some code

}
```

in your cntrls add handle button actions and call methods

```
// some code
[ClassName sendSMS];
// some code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I might end up using the Singleton implementation. Do you reckon using protocols is better in my case?